# No option to create a new Team Project in VS2015

Tags: git, tfs, visual-studio-2015

According to [this article on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/vs/alm/Overview/create-team-project), there should be an option for "New Team Project" under "Project and My Teams" in the Team Explorer window in Visual Studio:

[image]

However, I don't have "Projects and My Team", I just have "Projects", and I have no option to create a new Team Project.

[image]

If I choose "New Repository", it prompts me to make a new local repository, which I don't want (I have one set up for the project already).

If I choose "Manage Connections, I can successfully connect to my TFS server, but it closes the solution I'm working in, and I'm trying to add that existing solution to TFS.

Is there some configuration step I may have overlooked?

This is in VS 2015 Professional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to push an existing Git repository into a new Team Project in TFS. There's no way that I'm aware of to do it in one step.

First, create the Team Project by connecting to TFS via Visual Studio, as you've already done. It will close the solution you're working on, but that's fine -- you can create the Team Project at that point.

Once you have your team project created, you can add a remote to your existing repo and push it to your Team Project.

Comment: Ok, sounds reasonable.  Thanks!